# Plus signs ("+") disappears

Tags: php, html

I am sending sms to cellphones using PHP and an API key provided by my sms service provider.

The sms that I send reaches the target cellphone perfectly but the problem is when I have a `"+"` sign in my message the `"+"` do not appear in the cellphone. This is probably happening because the `"+"` sign is basically used for indicating a space.

When I run the api my code looks like following:

```
$msg="A+";
$x= file_get_contents("http://someurl...&msg=$msg");
```

Could you please tell me what to do to make the `"+"` appear in cellphones.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to look into using the function [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

```
$x = file_get_contents("http://someurl...&msg=" . urlencode($msg));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just tested the code and it is working perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)...

```
$msg="A+";
$msg = urlencode($msg);
$x= file_get_contents("http://someurl...&msg=$msg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use urlencode

```
$msg = urlencode("A+");
```

As php manual says:

> This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next
>   page.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$msg=urlencode("A+");

$x= file_get_contents("http://someurl...&msg=".$msg);
```

urlencode function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.